# Display widget on top of QVideoWidget with QMediaPlayer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qvideowidget

What I want to achieve is to have a button or a widget to be displayed on top of a QVideoWidget. Following [this](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/pyqt5-video-widget/) example of a sample video player, I tried to add a button on top of the QVideoWidget with the following code

```
self.button= QPushButton(videoWidget)
```

The button is displayed properly just as it should, but once I start playing the video file I open, the button disappears. I noticed if I hover my mouse over the location of the button, it briefly reappears before it disappears again, which makes me think that the button is being hidden by the QMediaPlayer which is being rerendered on top of everything for every frame.

How can I keep the button on top while the video is playing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a known problem since the drawing of the video is not directly done by Qt but OpenGL, a solution is to have a widget where the QVideoWidget is placed and in that widget place the button:

```
QWidget(container)
 ├── QVideoWidget
 └── QPushButton
```

Code:

```
# !/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets


class VideoWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Video Player Widget Example - pythonprogramminglanguage.com")

        self.mediaPlayer = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(None, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)

        videoWidget = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget()

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(videoWidget)

        buttonn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button", container)


        self.playButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.playButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.positionSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
        self.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)

        self.errorLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.errorLabel.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                                      QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)

        # Create new action
        openAction = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('open.png'), '&Open', self)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.setStatusTip('Open movie')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

        # Create exit action
        exitAction = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        # Create menu bar and add action
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        # fileMenu.addAction(newAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        # Create a widget for window contents
        wid = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)

        # Create layouts to place inside widget
        controlLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        controlLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.playButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.positionSlider)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(container)
        layout.addLayout(controlLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.errorLabel)

        # Set widget to contain window contents
        wid.setLayout(layout)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handleError)

    def openFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Movie",
                                                  QtCore.QDir.homePath())

        if fileName:
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))
            self.playButton.setEnabled(True)

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def mediaStateChanged(self, state):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        else:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))

    def positionChanged(self, position):
        self.positionSlider.setValue(position)

    def durationChanged(self, duration):
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, duration)

    def setPosition(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)

    def handleError(self):
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.errorLabel.setText("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoWindow()
    player.resize(640, 480)
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question so precisely and in detail, this is exactly what I was trying to figure out

Comment: now with Qt6 is this still working? because i tried this with Qt 6.4.2 c++ and the button QPushButton did not show up :( any idea?